# Express copy other than "^c"

Tags: python, copy, autohotkey

I want to add some extra step in my ctrl+C key. Basically, after I press ctrl+C, I will run a python code to process the content on the clipboard and update the clipboard with the processed text so I can paste it out.

```
^x::

clipboard =   
Sleep, 50
Send, ^c
ClipWait
Sleep, 50

Run "directory\try.py"
RunWait "directory\try.py"

Return
```

You can see that I used ^x because I don't want my test hotkey to keep calling on itself. I still want to use ^c to trigger the process, but in that case, I need to express "copy" in another term than "^c". Could someone help me out on this? I tried to google but found no helpful idea. Thanks.

Comment: You can use `Send, ^{Insert}` instead of `Send, ^c`.

Comment: I tried but then my code doesn't work anymore

Comment: Why both `run` and `runwait`? Probably you want `RunWait` only. So, put in a `MsgBox %Clipboard%` before the `Runwait` then add a `sleep  150` and another `MsgBox %Clipboard%` after to make sure the right things are happening.

Comment: @PGilm You're right. I originally though RunWait is more like a single wait without any run in it.

Comment: @LouieLee - @PGilm `send, ^{Insert}` is the right answer, but if you want an other way to do it, you can think about to make a Counter for example If you click 1x `^c` then do a action Copy and if you do click 2x `^c` then do a action Copy+run try.py - you can look to this example [multiclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522397/autohotkey-3-clicks-volume-mute/52570040#52570040) - You need only to change the code a little bit `~LButton::` into `^c::` and then split your Ahk example.

Comment: There's a way with PostMessage but maybe not reliable enough. See this topic towards the end: https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?p=265178

Comment: You can use `~^c::` to trigger your script. The tilde lets the key through, so you don't need to send it separately

Comment: @stevecody I tried ^{Insert} again but then AHK didn't work anymore again. I don't know why. Maybe because I'm using Windows?

Comment: @JackStoneS Yes! Your method works! Thanks!

Comment: I'll add it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `~^c::` to trigger your script. The tilde lets the key through, so you don't need to send it separately

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do MultiClick the Same Keyboard Shortcuts, that you can execute with different actions.

you can use this Ahk Example.

example.ahk

```
#SingleInstance force

;MultiClick the Same Keyboard Shortcuts to execute with different actions

esc::exitapp

^c::
ctrl_c_count++  ;start counter
SetTimer ctrl_c_action, -2
return

ctrl_c_action:
KeyWait, Ctrl
If (ctrl_c_count = 1)
{
MsgBox, ctrl_c_action 1 ;copy to clipboard
sendinput ^{insert} ;Express copy other than "^c"!
;.... any code for action 1
ctrl_c_count := 0
}
If (ctrl_c_count = 2)
{
MsgBox, ctrl_c_action 2 ;copy to clipboard & run Python Script.
sendinput ^{insert}
sleep 150
;Run "directory\try.py"
;....  any code for action 2      
ctrl_c_count := 0 
}     
return
```

Comment: You might want to add some braces and indenting. As you have it, in AHK, only the MsgBoxes are selectively triggered (first line after the `If`) and the `sendinput ^{insert}` will trigger twice, and the uncommented `RunWait "directory\try.py"` prt will always execute, too.

Comment: @PGilm - You are Right my mistake, i did change my answer with brackets - thanks